# Delay a script from activating until div opacity changed to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a series of div's each with numbers in them. I'd like it so that when you scroll down and the 2nd div fades in, only then will the numbers in that 2nd div start appearing. Right now, the numbers just load all at once.Should I maybe used `display:none` instead of `opacity`?

https://jsfiddle.net/gy9vLp4w/

```
setTimeout(
  function() {
    var animations = new Array();
    // queue all
    $(".owl-thumb-item").each(function() {
      animations.push($(this));
    });

    // start animating
    doAnimation(animations.shift());

    function doAnimation(image) {
      image.fadeIn("fast", function() {
        // wait until animation is done and recurse if there are more animations
        if (animations.length > 0) doAnimation(animations.shift());
      });
    }
  }, 1500);



$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each(function(i) {

      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * 1.3;

      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 900);

      }

    });

  });

});
```

Comment: why not use CSS transitions and just listen for [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) events, so that you trigger a transition on the div, wait for it to be done, then trigger a transition for the content of that div?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hi. :) Any chance you can show me with a fiddle? I'm still very new to all this. Would I be using `transition: 0.5sec all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tested and working!

I've implemented the following solution *- from what've understood -* please review the code comments and structure *(all seems to be clear)*.

**Some recommendations:**

- Improve your code and take another approach by trying to perform actions per `div` scrolled instead of all at once.
- In order to achieve what you need, one of the alternatives could be to take advantage of the `complete` config. from `jQuery` `animate` as I did or try to handle `CSS` transitions as someone suggested in the question comments.

**Live Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/1p751fz5/

---

**CSS:**

I've *"improved"* the `CSS` a bit.

```
div.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

div.block {
  height: 1000px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #d89d9d;
}

#two {
  background-color: #d85d9d;
}

#three {
  background-color: #000;
}

button {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML:**

I've added a third *"hidden"* `div` element for testing purposes.

```
<div id="one" class="block">
  <div class="owl-thumbs" data-slider-id="1">
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">01</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">02</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">03</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">04</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">05</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">06</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">07</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">08</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">09</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">10</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">11</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">12</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">13</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">14</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">15</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">16</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">17</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">18</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">19</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">20</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">21</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">22</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">23</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">24</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">25</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">26</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">27</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="two" class="hidden block">
  <div class="owl-thumbs" data-slider-id="2">
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">01</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">02</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">03</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">04</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">05</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">06</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">07</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">08</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">09</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">10</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">11</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">12</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">13</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">14</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">15</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">16</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">17</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">18</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">19</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">20</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">21</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">22</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">23</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">24</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">25</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">26</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">27</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="three" class="hidden block">
  <div class="owl-thumbs" data-slider-id="3">
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">01</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">02</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">03</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">04</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">05</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">06</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">07</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">08</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">09</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">10</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">11</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">12</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">13</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">14</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">15</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">16</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">17</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">18</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">19</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">20</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">21</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">22</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">23</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">24</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">25</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">26</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">27</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
// constants
var BTN_CLS = 'owl-thumb-item',
    BTN_ANIMATION_MILLIS = 200,
    DIV_ANIMATION_MILLIS = 1000;

// document ready handler
$(document).ready(function() {

  // display buttons from first 'div'
  showBtns('one', BTN_CLS);

  // window scroll handler
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.hidden').each(function(i, v) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top) {
        // show 'div' when scrolling
        showDiv($(this), onCompleteDivAnimation($(this)));
      }
    });
  });

});

/**
 * Used to show an animated 'div' and perform some actions.
 * @param {Function} completeCallback Action performed after animation.
 * @param {Object} div Target element.
 */
function showDiv(div, completeCallback) {
  // check if 'div' is currently animated and avoid animation queue
  if (!div.is(':animated')) {
    div.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, {
      complete: completeCallback,
      duration: DIV_ANIMATION_MILLIS
    });
  }
};

/**
 * Used to perform actions after completing a 'div' animation.
 */
function onCompleteDivAnimation(div) {
    showBtns(div.prop('id'), BTN_CLS);
};

/**
 * Used to show button(s) from a 'div' element.
 * @param {String} divId Target element Id.
 * @param {String} btnCls Button(s) CSS class.
 */
function showBtns(divId, btnCls) {
  var btnGroup = getBtnGroup(divId, btnCls);

  animateBtn(btnGroup);
};

/**
 * Used for creating a group of button(s) from a 'div' element.
 * @param {String} divId Target element Id.
 * @param {String} btnCls Button(s) CSS class.
 * @returns {Array} btnGroup
 */
function getBtnGroup(divId, btnCls) {
  var domBtns = $('#' + divId + ' .' + btnCls),
    btnGroup = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < (domBtns || []).length; ++i) {
    btnGroup.push(domBtns[i]);
  }

  return btnGroup;
};

/**
 * Used to animate a button group that normally comes from a 'div' element.
 * @param {Array} btnGroup
 */
function animateBtn(btnGroup) {
    btnGroup = btnGroup || [];

  $(btnGroup.shift()).fadeIn(BTN_ANIMATION_MILLIS, function() {
    if (btnGroup.length > 0) {
      animateBtn(btnGroup);
    }
  });
};
```

Hope this helps.

*Enjoy!*

Comment: Thank you! I just have one more question. How do I make it so that the hidden becomes visible when the div doesn't touch the top but half way through the viewport?  I've been trying to change `$(this).offset().top)` to `$(window).height()/2;`

Comment: @user2252219 You mean, half of the visible div?

Comment: I just meant that as the hidden div is scrolled upwards, it will become visible when it reaches at the halfway mark of the viewport. Right now, it becomes visible when it touches the top of the viewport. :)